# Gazebo not running on ROS Kinetic and Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run Gazebo on a virtual machine with ROS Kinetic and Ubuntu 16.04.

However, I ran into the following error. I searched it online. Some says to change SIGINT to INT. It still doesn't work. Could anyone help me with this?

VMware: vmw_ioctl_command error Invalid argument. Aborted (core dumped) /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/gazebo_ros/gazebo: 46: kill: invalid signal number or name: SIGINT

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261851/gazebo-not-running-on-ros-kinetic-and-ubuntu-16.04/) by [stephen127](https://answers.ros.org/users/30410/stephen127/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-05-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think this may be similar to the error I was getting, which was related to accelerated 3d graphics in VMware Workstation. You could try doing what I did:

add the following to ~/.bashrc

```
export SVGA_VGPU10=0
```

Or maybe try disabling 'Accelerate 3D graphics' inside the vm settings.

---

Originally posted by [youngiif](https://answers.ros.org/users/30398/youngiif/) with karma: 86 on 2017-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stephen127](https://answers.ros.org/users/30410/stephen127/) on 2017-05-16**:
Adding the command line to the bash file did resolve my issue. But disable the "Accelerate 3D graphics" did. Thanks!

**Comment by [youngiif](https://answers.ros.org/users/30398/youngiif/) on 2017-05-16**:
Glad to hear it worked.  I should have mentioned that if you use that .bashrc change, you would need to start gazebo from the terminal and not start it from the gui in order for the option to be applied.

**Comment by [stephen127](https://answers.ros.org/users/30410/stephen127/) on 2017-05-17**:
I did start the Gazebo from terminal after adding that command in the .bashrc. For some reason, it did not resolve the issue on my computer.

**Comment by [rjb0026](https://answers.ros.org/users/35759/rjb0026/) on 2018-06-08**:
`export SVGA_VGPU10=0`

Worked for me w/ ROS kinetic/gazebo 7 in VMware workstation 14 (Ubuntu 16.04). Went from 5-6 FPS w/ 3-D graphics disabled to 60+ FPS w/ 3-D graphics enabled.

**Comment by [yashsahu](https://answers.ros.org/users/58407/yashsahu/) on 2020-08-22**:
just disabling 'Accelerate 3D graphics' inside the vm settings worked for me, thanks.
Ubuntu 20.04, ROS Noetic